# Can coordinating-conjunctions be omitted from a list?

Tags: lists, coordinating-conjunctions

This is a question I've wondered for a while.

Examples:

1. I'm drained, confused, frustrated.
2. I'm tired, lonely.

Can "and" be omitted if the sentence retains its clarity?

Comment: Omitting the conjunction is commonly literary or poetic. See *[asyndeton](http://literarydevices.net/asyndeton/)*.

Answer (score 2):

A rhetorical device which can be used to good effect is called *asyndeton*, which obviates the use of a conjunction at the end of a series. Used in moderation it can serve to give your readers (or listeners) the feeling of a climax, especially when the last word in the series is perhaps the most important. Examples:

> We spent the afternoon discussing, listening, learning, changing.
>
> We could clearly see that the body was motionless, pale, dead.

What is the difference between the following two sentences, either in how they scan or in how they sound?

> - She was all grace, style, and perfection.
> - She was all grace, style, perfection.

Which of the following sentences gives the impression the list is somehow incomplete and, perhaps, could go on and on and on?

> - As a magician, I can make thing disappear: coins, cards, rabbits, and people.
> - As a magician, I can make things disappear: coins, cards, rabbits, people.

Play with asyndeton, but use it sparingly. There is a time for a nice, neat list which includes a conjunction. There is also a time for a nice, neat list with a twist: no conjunction!

Comment: Julius Caesar said, "I came, I saw, I conquered." This is an isocolon--a figure of speech in which a sentence is composed by two or more parts (cola) that are perfectly equivalent in structure, length, and rhythm. The Latin "veni, vidi, vici" is classified as a hendiatris--a figure of speech used for emphasis, in which three words are used to express one idea (in this case, a swift, decisive victory). Omitting the conjunction can be poetic, dramatic, effective. But, as @rhetorician notes, do so sparingly. Too much and it becomes tired, trite, contrived.

Comment: @surlawda: But not your "tired, trite, contrived," of course! Don

Answer (score 0):

It's preferable to insert the cooordinator *and* before the last item in the list:

*I'm drained, confused and frustrated*.

*I'm lonely and tired.*